# How to Get InnerHTML for Table Cell instead of an object or NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am attempting to create a string that contains all of the data within an HTML table using JavaScript (open to changing to JQuery). By using this method below, I receive an NaN value, instead of the data (numbers).

```
function Ard() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tblData");
    var dataStr = "";
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
      for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
          var toAdd = col;
          dataStr += toAdd;
      }
    }
};
```

I have also tried a jQuery method but it only returned an HTML object. It should be noted that when printing the 'col' value to the console, the data is collected properly (actual values).

The table I'm using is editable by the user, but it saves as a standard HTML table. Here is the basic code for the table below if it helps solve the problem.

```
<table id="tblData" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Treatment Number</th>
            <th>Cell Number</th>
            <th>Waste Container Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas towards how to get the innerHTML and add it properly to the string?

I would also like to do this with a row by column loop (set of two for or each loops maybe?) so that I know what column I'm grabbing from.

Comment: Could you add some sample data to that table, and post the string you expect the JavaScript to produce. Because creating a string from a table is easy, creating the string *you require* needs rather more information. Incidentally, there is no need whatsoever to use jQuery for something like this, most Array, String and table-manipulation methods are cross browser (with the exception of some of the 'better' ECMAScript 6 methods).

Comment: The `thead` contains a `row` too. The values of which would resolve to `NaN`.

Comment: Its as if any data were in that table, the contents are insignificant, they're just numbers, dates, or times. I'm just trying to get a string, preferably through a row loop and then a column loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are OK to use jquery,

```js
var dataStr = "";
$('#tblData > tbody').each(function(e) {
  dataStr += $(this).text();
});
console.log(dataStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblData" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Treatment Number</th>
      <th>Cell Number</th>
      <th>Waste Container Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>10101</td>
      <td>20202</td>
      <td>30303</td>
      <td>40404</td>
      <td>50505</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>wowowo</td>
      <td>sksksk</td>
      <td>alalal</td>
      <td>qpqpqp</td>
      <td>zmzmzm</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want the `dataStr` to have the `<td>` tags also, you should use,

```
dataStr += $(this).html()
```

**EDIT**

If you also want to access the current column index, you can use this. But here, the `dataStr` would finally contain a single line string concatenating all the texts inside `<td>` tags.

```
$('#tblData > tbody > tr > td').each(function(e) {
  var currentColNo = $(this).index();
  dataStr += $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: The function Ard() actually already links up to a button on the page, anyway I can change your code so that still works?

Comment: Yes you can paste my jquery code inside your `Ard()` function to get it working. Do you want `dataStr` to contain the `<td>` tags also?

Comment: It doesn't seem to add to the dataStr, simply redefine it

Comment: I am not cleat what you meant by that?

Comment: @Coleen I have edited the answer. Now `dataStr` contains the entire data as a single string. I think that is what you wanted? Copy the entire code inside your `Ard()` function and see.

Comment: Yep it works out. I edited the question a while back, and was hoping to get a row by column kind of loop in order to know which column I'm on. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I have added a edit at the end of the answer. See whether that is what you wanted.

Comment: I still wanted the text in this, but that's an easy change on my side! Thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could select all rows and the iterate over them and get the text:

```
var str = "", values = [];
$("#tblData").find('tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
    //You can concatenate a string or push the values to an array
    str += $(this).text();
    values.push($(this).text());
});

console.log(str, values);
```

Comment: How can I get this to one string variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure js:

```
function Ard() {
    var table = document.querySelectorAll("#tblData tr th");
    var dataStr = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
       dataStr += table[i].innerHTML;
    }
};
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hnyLLp48/)

Comment: Trying this solution but it says the < is an unexpected token. I think it has to do with how chrome adds comments but not positive. Any ideas? Also is there anyway to do it by row then cell so I can know which column I'm on?

Comment: I fixed the unexpected token, but the string only seems to return the table headings, even with table data.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all text from the table `<td>`s and post it into a textarea (just for demonstration purposes):

```js
$('#out').val($('#tblData td').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblData" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Treatment Number</th>
            <th>Cell Number</th>
            <th>Waste Container Number</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>some</td><td>extra</td><td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<textarea id="out" rows=10 cols=60></textarea>
```

**Update:**

If you "just" want to put the `<td>` contents into a single variable you could do:

```
var str=$('#tblData td').text()
```

I extended your example so you will actually get a result.

Comment: I'm actually not trying to print it out, I just want a variable that is a string containing all <td>s